# R building a subset based on value in previous row

Tags: r, row, subset

I have a problem figuering this out:
suppose this is how my data looks like:

```
Num condition     y
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   b   4
5   b   5
6   b   6
7   c   7
8   c   8
9   c   9
10  b   10
11  b   11
12  b   12
```

I now want to make calculation (e.g., mean) on b, depending on whether value was in the row before b, in this example a or c?
Thanks for any help!!!
Angelika

Comment: To make it easier to help you, can you please add an example of your expected output. Should the value preceeding 'b' determine if a calculation is performed at all? Or do you want to perform different calculations? Please be more specific.

Comment: Hi Henrik, thanks a lot for answering! I will need to make calculations on the values in y about all b's that are either preceded by a or c - so the sum of b preceded of b for example (15) or sum of b preceded by c (33). Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
# in order to separate between different runs of condition 'b',
# get length and value of runs of equal values of 'condition'
rl <- rle(x = df$condition)
df$run <- rep(x = seq_len(length(rl$lengths)), times = rl$lengths)

# calculate sum of y, on data grouped by condition and run, and where condition is 'b'
aggregate(y ~ condition + run, data = df, subset = condition == "b", sum)
```

Comment: Hi Henrik, thanks a lot for your answer. It works! But in case of my data, the thing is still more complicated - the data looks a bit like this:Num Condition Gaze_time AOI_Hit
1 a 20 1
2 a 20 1
3 b 10 0
4 b 30 1
7 c 10 1
8 b 50 1
9 b 50 1
10 b 10 0
11 b 60 1      I want now make calculations on Gaze_Time, depending on whether AOI_Hit is a 0 or 1 - but also separeted depeding if "b" is preceded by "a" or by "c". I hope this is comprehensible...Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "lagged" condition column to your dataframe (assuming `DF`) using

```
> DF <- within(DF, lag_cond <- c(NA, head(as.character(condition), -1)))
```

Result:

```
   Num condition  y lag_cond
     1         a  1     <NA>
     2         a  2        a
     3         a  3        a
     4         b  4        a
     5         b  5        b
     6         b  6        b
     7         c  7        b
     8         c  8        c
     9         c  9        c
    10         b 10        c
    11         b 11        b
    12         b 12        b
```

Now you can identify rows you want like this:

```
> DF[with(DF, condition=="b" & lag_cond %in% c("a","c")),]
   Num condition  y lag_cond
     4         b  4        a
    10         b 10        c
```

Comment: Hi Ferdinand.kraft, thanks for the answer. In my dataset, however, this will not work, as its eye tracking data and there are a lot of NA's between. Also, in the example, there are always the same number of rows, which is not the case in my real data